# How to make the date field of authoring information in Create Article page a date field?

Tags: 7, forms, datetime, nodes

In the page to create new article, at the bottom in the authored on tab, how do I make the date textbox to a date field with date picker? I mean, I want it to be easy for the publisher to choose custom date.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Date Popup Authored](http://drupal.org/project/date_popup_authored) module.

> Date Popup Authored provides a jQuery UI datepicker for the Authored
>   on date field found on node submission forms.
>
> This allows content editors to pick a human-understandable date and
>   not have to type the exact date format of the default Authored on
>   field.